How to build a $6\times 6\times 6$ cube using 4-unit T-shaped pieces?
I am trying to solve a 3D block puzzle. It consists of 54 T-shaped pieces, each made up of 4 units, shaped as follows:
$$ \square \\ \square\square\square $$
The goal of the puzzle is to build a $6\times6\times6$ cube using these pieces. I'm currently trying to solve it by brute force but if anyone can think of an elegant approach to solve the puzzle please let me know! Additionally, I'm curious to know if there's only one solution or multiple (and what the proof would be for this)!

Here is a solution on YouTube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izKIq8RlZoY
In case you are unable or unwilling to watch the above video, here are three snapshots showing how to build a $2 \times 6 \times 6$ block:



After building the $2 \times 6 \times 6$ block, build two more $2 \times 6 \times 6$ blocks on top of it.
